# How to get the text of the top most parent of list item in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following design of a `ul list`.

```
<ul>
    <li class="category">
        Design
        <ul>
            <li>Graphic Design</li>
            <li>Web Design </li>
            <li>HTML</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>Print</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="category">
        Development
        <ul>
            <li>PHP</li>
            <li>Java</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now what I want is if you click on the "CSS" item ,I want to get the text of its parent i.e "Design".
I have tried the following code but I got the whole list in it.

```
$('ul').on("click", "li", function (e) {
    console.log("Child Clicked: "+$(this).text()+" Parent: "+$(this).parents(".category").text());
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing this part

```
$(this).parents(".category").text()
```

with

```
$(this).parents(".category")[0].childNodes[0].textContent;
```

childNodes returns all the child elements including text nodes.

If you want to use jQuery only, then wrap this textnode inside a span

```
<ul>
    <li class="category">
        <span>Design</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Graphic Design</li>
            <li>Web Design </li>
            <li>HTML</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>Print</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="category">
        <span>Development</span>
        <ul>
            <li>PHP</li>
            <li>Java</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and fetch that first node's text using

```
$(this).parents(".category span").html()
```

Another approach could be to use `contents` and `filter` of jquery

```
$(this).parents(".category").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).nodeValue;
```

Comment: It worked thank you, but I am bound to use the jquery ,is there anyway we can accomplish it with jquery?

Comment: @BilalHussain Not sure if jquery gives enough to work with jquery. In fact you should change your markup to include that text inside a span or some other element

Comment: `.filter()` can be used.

Comment: using span can be helpful. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

just change :

```
console.log("Child Clicked: "+$(this).text()+" Parent: "+$(this).parents(".category").text());
```

with :

```
console.log("Child Clicked: "+$(this).text()+" Parent: "+$(this).parent().text());
```

Comment: It returns a whole list of the currently clicked item.

Comment: then you can select the first one , eg : **$(this).parent()[0]**

Comment: actually the parent item I want is not in the list, it just gives me the siblings item list.